# Use array of IDs to insert records into table if it does not already exist

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have created a postgresql function that takes a comma separated list of ids as input parameter. I then convert this comma separated list into an array.

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunction(csvIDs text)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE ids INT[];
BEGIN
 ids = string_to_array(csvIDs,',');

  -- INSERT INTO tableA

END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

What I want to do now is to INSERT a record for each of the id's(in the array) into TABLE A if the ID does not already exist in table. The new records should have value field set to 0.

Table is created like this

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    value int
);
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unnest() function to get each element of your array.

> ```
> create table tableA (id int);
> insert into tableA values(13);
> ```

> ```
> select t.ids
> from  (select unnest(string_to_array('12,13,14,15', ',')::int[]) ids) t
> ```
>
> ```
> | ids |
> | --: |
> |  12 |
> |  13 |
> |  14 |
> |  15 |
> ```

Now you can check if `ids` value exists before insert a new row.

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION myFunction(csvIDs text)
> RETURNS int AS 
> $myFunction$
> DECLARE
>     r_count int;
> BEGIN
>
>     insert into tableA
>     select t.ids
>     from   (select unnest(string_to_array(csvIDs,',')::int[]) ids) t
>     where  not exists (select 1 from tableA where id = t.ids);
>     GET DIAGNOSTICS r_count = ROW_COUNT;
>     return r_count;
>
> END; 
> $myFunction$
> LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
> ```

> ```
> select myFunction('12,13,14,15') as inserted_rows;
> ```
>
> ```
> | inserted_rows |
> | ------------: |
> |             3 |
> ```

> ```
> select * from tableA;
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> | 13 |
> | 12 |
> | 14 |
> | 15 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a81a6c737ab78955af45443343001b29)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, how would this work if I have more fields on tableA that needs to be set (Value field should be set to 0, my question is updated). Also if I call this function again with ('14,15') how do I get only 15 to be inserted as 14 has already been inserted?

Comment: You should pass this fields as a function parameters.

Comment: I'm glad to help.